# findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout) returns null

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a problem with the the following line:

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
```

returning null.

For debugging purpose, I have tried the XML file found on the official Android DrawerLayout tutorial:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And this is the top of my FragmentActivity file:

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PuzzleAllActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private ProgressDialog dialog;

private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_puzzle_all);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if(mDrawerLayout == null){
        Log.d("DEBUG", "Drawer layout is null");
    }
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.menu_icon, R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close) {

        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            //getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            //getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        }
    };

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

For some reason, mDrawerLayout is null, which gives me a java.lang.NullPointerException for the last line:

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

I'm relative new to Android programming and have no clue what could cause this problem.

I have made sure that Support Libraries in the project build path are checked.

This is the error I get:

```
02-15 22:12:03.712: E/AndroidRuntime(17259): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-15 22:12:03.712: E/AndroidRuntime(17259): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.puzzleall.puzzleall/com.puzzleall.puzzleall.PuzzleAllActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-15 22:12:03.712: E/AndroidRuntime(17259):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
02-15 22:12:03.712: E/AndroidRuntime(17259):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
02-15 22:12:03.712: E/AndroidRuntime(17259):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
02-15 22:12:03.712: E/AndroidRuntime(17259):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
02-15 22:12:03.712: E/AndroidRuntime(17259):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-15 22:12:03.712: E/AndroidRuntime(17259):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
02-15 22:12:03.712: E/AndroidRuntime(17259):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
02-15 22:12:03.712: E/AndroidRuntime(17259):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-15 22:12:03.712: E/AndroidRuntime(17259):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-15 22:12:03.712: E/AndroidRuntime(17259):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
02-15 22:12:03.712: E/AndroidRuntime(17259):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
02-15 22:12:03.712: E/AndroidRuntime(17259):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-15 22:12:03.712: E/AndroidRuntime(17259): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-15 22:12:03.712: E/AndroidRuntime(17259):    at com.puzzleall.puzzleall.PuzzleAllActivity.onCreate(PuzzleAllActivity.java:71)
02-15 22:12:03.712: E/AndroidRuntime(17259):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5267)
02-15 22:12:03.712: E/AndroidRuntime(17259):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
02-15 22:12:03.712: E/AndroidRuntime(17259):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
```

I appreciate any help I can get :)

Comment: Can you confirm that the XML file you posted is named "activity_puzzle_all.xml".  I don't think there's a problem with your code after going through the question, so my first thought is that maybe you're accidentally referencing a different layout file.

Comment: Code seems legit. Are you sure XML is named activity_puzzle_all.xml and placed under layout folder?

Comment: Did you maybe recently change the id in your layout xml? Could be the R wasn't regenerated till then and because of that it does not find the id? Try clean & build in eclipse to force your R file to be generated again and see if it helps

Comment: I will triple-check my code When I'm back at the office, but I'm pretty sure that I'm refering to the correct XML file. I have been using it for a long time, but it started giving me errors today when I was implementing a new drawerlayout. I have tried cleaning the project many times. I was testing it today on Samsung Galaxy Tab 3, not an AVD

Comment: I just realized without looking at the code what the problem is :) I hav separate layouts for portrait and landscape and didn't update all the layout files. A silly mistake which probably won't be repeated.

Comment: MattDavis, how do I accept your comment as an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NullPointer exception was caused by different layout files("layout" and "layout-land").

The Landscape version had an old layout file without a DrawerLayout. So when it got inflated, I got a NullPointer Exception when referring to the DrawerLayout.